# Count the number of times a string appeared in a delimited field In BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

I have a dataset with a delimiter "->" like:

```
ROW 1- "Q -> Res -> tes -> Res -> twet"
ROW 2- "rw -> gewg -> tes -> Res -> twet"
ROW 3- "Y -> Res -> Res -> Res -> twet"
```

I just want to count the number of "Res" in every row

Output would be:

```
ROW 1- 2
ROW 2- 1
ROW 3- 3
```

Ive tried writing the following queries but they arnt counting correctly or only counting once:

```
    countif(distinct(lower(FIELD_NAME) like '%Res%'))

    count(split(regexp_extract(FIELD_NAME, '(.*?)Res'), '->')) 

    (trim(Array_reverse(split(regexp_extract(FIELD_NAME, '(.*?)Res'),   '->')))

    count(regexp_extract(trim(FIELD_NAME), 'Res')) 

    count(regexp_contains(trim(FIELD_NAME), 'Res'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below

```
select id, 
  ( select count(*)
    from unnest(split(text, ' -> ')) word
    where word = 'Res'
  ) cnt
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try and consider the below approach using `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL()`:

```sql
select str,
  array_length(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, r'\sRes\s')) as Res_count
  from your_table
```

**Output:**

[image]

You may refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) documentation for more information in using this BigQuery string function.